# Can setForeground() be used by multiple services with same notification?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, foreground-service

I know that `startForeground(notification_ID, notification)` makes the service stronger in terms of not being destroyed by the system. But can the same notification be used to keep 2 or 3 services alive or is this privilege passed to the service that called it last?

Comment: Why do you have "2 or 3 services" that would be running simultaneously and all need to be part of the foreground?

Comment: because they do different things. Depending on what features the user wants activated there could be just one or there could be three. It's easier to handle the prefference changes if those features are implemented in different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use same notification ID. Only one notification with specific ID can exist.
Or bind service and let main one run on foreground, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html